# Is it possibule to insert 200 JPG image together in the excel file with the same size into its cell?

Tags: excel, image

I have 2000 JPG images in a folder & I want to insert all those pictures in a column of excel file into its cells with the same size.So,request you to kindly provide me the easy way to do the job in the short time.

Best Regards
Sant

Answer (score 3):

this will help you:

http://en.allexperts.com/q/Excel-1059/2009/12/Excel-2007-VBA-insert.htm

Comment: Thank you very much for providing me such a wonderful formula.
Santosh